# Personal hotspot blue bar problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

When I launch my application while some device is connected to my iPhone (hence, a blue bar showing the number of connection will be shown), my launch image (Default.png) gets deformed and the size no longer fits the screen size.

How can I solve this problem? I have tried to check the "status bar initially hidden" but it only helps after the startup image is loaded.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

There isn’t really a way around this. If I remember correctly, the system adjusts the launch image for double-height status bars by cutting out some portion of its middle; your only option to mitigate this problem is to figure out which part of your Default.png is getting cut out and change the image so that that removal isn’t as noticeable.

Comment: I'm reaching the same conclusion but I'm looking for a confirmation somewhere in the documentation. Do you remember where you saw that info?

Comment: I’ve never seen it in the documentation, but you can experimentally verify it by triggering the double-height status bar (recording audio, for instance) and opening any app that has a launch image with its logo in the middle. **edited** Actually, I just tried this with a couple of apps and as of iOS 6 it’s definitely no longer cutting out the middle—the Google Search app, for instance, has its logo in the middle and looks fine. Not sure where the additional 20 points are coming from now.

Comment: Definitely was happening to me in iOS 7.0.x but as of iOS 7.1 doesn't seem to be happening anymore.

Comment: are there any news for iOS 8 & 9? It looks like the images only get deformed

Answer (score 2):

You can fix this problem by using a storyboard as a launch screen instead of images.
Create a new storyboard and add a UIViewcontroller as the initial view controller. Layout your startup screen using constraints. For example: place your logo in the center with a UIImageView.
Open your project's settings and in targets select general. Scroll down to 'App Icons and Launch Images'. Select the storyboard you just created where it says 'Launch Screen File'.