# Launch screen doesn't fully cover the screen in hotspot mode

Tags: ios, iphone

If I activate the hotspot on my iPhone, the launch screen is moved up and on the bottom of the screen I have a padding space where I can see the phone's home screen.

[image]

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8078697/view-of-the-page-broken-when-personal-hotspot-feature-turned-on

Comment: I solved the problem on navigation controller and every view as I said. My question is about launch screen where I don't have the same control.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6183128/personal-hotspot-blue-bar-problem

Comment: thanks, but it doesn't help me at all

Comment: Did you use autolayout?

Comment: Yes, of course I use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution of this problem. In AppDelegate.m I added this method:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application willChangeStatusBarFrame:(CGRect)newStatusBarFrame {
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];
}
```

The launch screen looks perfect.

Comment: Deprecated in iOS 9. Have to use `UIViewController prefersStatusBarHidden` but since we don't have a view controller, we can no longer do this.